# Executing Spring Boot Integration tests on existing mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am using spring boot 2 and I am trying to execute integration tests on repositories by creating tests with annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository repository;

    // CONTENT    
}
```

I have liquibase migrations and I want those tests to be run on special mysql database. However spring boot by default is trying to configure embeded h2 database. And after removing h2 dependencies from POM file I have got:

```
Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoconfigureTestDatabase
```

When I run my application it runs perfectly fine, since I have filled `application.yml` with proper database connections. However when I add application.yml to test resources nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me how to configure those tests properly to use mysql database?

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` uses `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` - try using `@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager` and `@AutoConfigureDataJpa`

Comment: have you configured your datasource in your app.properties? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` uses `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` and it replaces your configured database by default. You can override it by using `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)` on your test class.